# Loading images of "Next" TableView Cell Asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, sdwebimage

So I am using SDWebImage to load images into the cells.

I want to preload images of the next few cells so that when the user scrolls, the image is already loaded.

Whats the ideal way to do this.

Current code -->

```
[cell.BGImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:section.imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceholderF"]];
```

Ensuring that the current displayed image is kept at priority loading.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SDWebImageDownloader` method to download image before your cell load or in other controller. So it will cache image and when your cell load it will show immediately.

```
[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader]downloadImageWithURL:nil options:SDWebImageDownloaderContinueInBackground progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {

}];
```

and you can set download image priority in LIFO manner using below code.

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager].imageDownloader setExecutionOrder:SDWebImageDownloaderLIFOExecutionOrder];
```

Maybe this will help you.